# How can I install package for using at command?

Tags: debian

In my debian box, I want to use at command, but got this:

> -bash: at: command not found

Which package should I install?

Thank!

Comment: crontab. Is already installed. try `man crontab`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is called "at".

[Debian Package Details here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/at)

Comment: To install at, why must install so many extra packages?

Comment: @Mike.G It's not that many.

Comment: There are obviously a number of dependencies for getting the "at" command to work.

Comment: It's a mailer daemon it drags in (exim). Kind of weird dependency?

Comment: Free software works that way, if it makes sense for the developer to use a certain library or tool then they do so and it adds a *weird* dependency.

Comment: at wants to mail the result of the jobs it runs to the user invoking it. So it need a mailer. It is highly unusual not having at least a rudimential mailer, to at least send mail to a smarthost doing the real mailing.